# Pull changes from file1 to file2 in git

Tags: git

In a GIT repo, a few months back, I did 'mv file1 file2' (unix move) and committed file2 into my repo. Now when file1 is updated in the master and I pull from it, the changes don't automatically make it into my repo's file2. I have read in this forum that this should have worked whether I did unix 'mv' or 'git mv'. Anyways, here is where I am. Now, is there a way I can make GIT understand that 'file1' and 'file2' are the same file and changes in file1 should go into file2 when doing 'git pull'?

Comment: Your question is missing some details. What do you mean by "updated in the master?" Master is usually used to refer to a branch name. Are you referring to a branch, or to another copy of the repo somewhere else? If you're referring to another copy of the repo, are they in-sync, or are you doing something more complicated than a simple pull?

Comment: Yes, by master, I am referring to another copy of the repo. Not sure what you mean by "are they in-sync". I am simply pulling from that repo to get that repo's changes.

Comment: By 'in-sync' I meant you're pulling from a branch in the other repo to a matching branch locally. If so, it doesn't make sense for the changes to take place in an alternate file locally. If you moved and committed the file, but you're in sync with the remote, that means you must have pushed that change back to the remote. If not, you're *not* in sync.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need to do is to figure out what changes there are between `file1` and `file2` now, i.e., `diff -u file1 file2 > patch`. Store that away, look it over, perhaps even edit `patch` to get rid of unneded changes (careful, the format isn't desiged for editing!). Then tell git about the renaming, `git mv file1 file2`, perhaps applying the patch saved from earlier. You can now `git push` the result, and your woes should be over.

PS: *Do not* trust what somebody on the other end of the world tells you here. Check carefully that the advise applies to your case, they might have misunderstood. Experiment with a scratch copy of the repository until you are satisfied you know what is going on.